Deploy Tensorflow MoveNet for (near) real-time pose estimation
For a school project we are creating an application that performs pose estimation on children doing physical tests. Children are filmed using tablets. The frames get sent to a server for processing since the tablets are not powerfull enough to do the pose estimation. The server then performs the pose estimation using Tensorflow MoveNet Thunder and sends some data back to the tablet.
Currently we use Django server side and have a react-native app running on the tablets. For the communication, we set up a websocket between the tablet and the server to send the frames from the tablet to the server and send the data from the server to the tablet. The frames are base64 encoded before transmission.
const base64Image = data.toString('base64');

const message = {
   'frame_index': i,
   'frame': base64Image,
   'is_last_frame': i === amountOfFrames,
   'test_child_id': test_child_id
};
// console.log("Sending message:", message)
// Send to websocket with the image data
jumping_sidways_socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));

We know notice that the transmission of the frames to the server is responsible for the biggest part of the delay making it difficult to have near real-time processing of the frames. The question if it is possible to increase the transfer speed?

Hi @florNeufKens,To improve the transmission speed and reducing the delay. There are some ways you can do, you can compress image size, send multiple frames per webSocket message, also you can adjust the frame rate.
